Time fluctuating
// Determine next month and year
$nextMonthDate = new DateTime('first day of next month');
$nextMonthName = $nextMonthDate->format('F');
$nextYear = $nextMonthDate->format('Y');

// ...

$currentDate = new Date();
const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();

if (currentDay <= 7) {
    currentTimerText = 'Time Remaining';
    upcomingTimerText = 'Registration Starts';
}else{
    currentTimerText = 'Registration Closed';
    upcomingTimerText = 'Registration Ends';
}

// ...

const currentTimerEnd = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, Math.min(7, lastDayOfCurrentMonth), 23, 59, 59);
const upcomingTimerEnd = new Date(upcomingMonthYear, upcomingMonth, Math.min(7, lastDayOfUpcomingMonth), 23, 59, 59);

// ...

function calculateTimeRemaining(endDate) {
    const now = new Date();
    const timeRemaining = endDate - now;
    const days = Math.floor(timeRemaining / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((timeRemaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    return {
        days,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds
    };
}

// ...

function startCountdown(element, endDate) {
    function updateCountdown() {
        const { days, hours, minutes, seconds } = calculateTimeRemaining(endDate);
        element.innerHTML = `
            <div class="m-table__itm"><span>${days}</span><span>DAYS</span></div>
            <div class="m-table__itm"><span>${hours}</span><span>HRS</span></div>
            <div class="m-table__itm"><span>${minutes}</span><span>MIN</span></div>
            <div class="m-table__itm"><span>${seconds}</span><span>SEC</span></div>
        `;
        if (endDate > new Date()) {
            setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = '<div class="m-table__itm"><span>-</span><span>DAYS</span></div><div class="m-table__itm"><span>-</span><span>HRS</span></div><div class="m-table__itm"><span>-</span><span>MIN</span></div><div class="m-table__itm"><span>-</span><span>SEC</span></div>';
        }
    }
    updateCountdown();
}

// ...

const currentEndDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentMonth + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59);
const upcomingEndDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentMonth + 2, 0, 23, 59, 59);

// ...

if (currentDay <= 7) {
    startCountdown(document.getElementById('countdown-0'), currentTimerEnd);
    startCountdown(document.getElementById('countdown-1'), currentTimerEnd);
}else{
    startCountdown(document.getElementById('countdown-0'), currentTimerEnd);
    startCountdown(document.getElementById('countdown-1'), upcomingTimerEnd);
}

I am using this code for a competition, and it includes a countdown timer. The problem I'm facing is that the countdown time is fluctuating. For example, it should show 5 days, 10 hours, 3 minutes, and 45 seconds, but for a second, it shows 59 days, 10 hours, 3 minutes, and 45 seconds. This flicker in the days occurs every time it counts down. I'm not sure why this is happening. Please help me resolve this issue.

The countdown timer should be running in JavaScript. How is the PHP code related?

$currentDate = new Date(); const currentDay = currentDate.getDate();. The variable you assigned is not the same one you're calling the method on.

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Instead of calling setTimeout() repeatedly, why not use setInterval()?

Welcome to SO! As said, a minimal reproducible example is very helpful - for us to see what you do without reading pages, and sometimes for you because you find your error while you are preparing this!

I would recommend fixing the title as it's not descriptive of the problem nor specific by any means
